SpriteKit: Increasing camera scale causes jagged edges
I have a scene (code below) in which some nodes should always visually appear to have the same size in the viewport. To achieve this I scale them in sync with the cameraScale. The problem that I am facing is, that changing the camera scale causes jagged edges on my shapes. The nodes themselves use anti-aliasing but the scene itself seems to be downsampled without any interpolation. It looks the downscaling just uses "nearest neighbor" instead of something like "bicubic" resampling which would produce smoother edges.
Is there a way to change the downscaling algorithm in SKScene? Or is there some other workaround for this? I imagine this must be a common issue in any game that uses the camera to zoom in/out of the scene.
Camera Scale set to "1"

Camera Scale set to "50"

class MyScene: SKScene {
    let cameraNode = SKCameraNode()

    override func sceneDidLoad() {
        self.camera = cameraNode
        addChild(cameraNode)
        scaleMode = .resizeFill
    }

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let cameraScale: CGFloat = 50.0

        cameraNode.xScale = cameraScale
        cameraNode.yScale = cameraScale

        let width = 300 * cameraScale

        let shape = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: width))
        shape.position = CGPoint(x: view.frame.centerX, y: view.frame.centerY)
        shape.lineWidth = 2 * cameraScale
        shape.zRotation = 20
        addChild(shape)
    }
}


perhaps i misunderstand your use case, but "best practice" for keeping nodes static to camera is to attach them to the camera rather than to the root node of the scene. hence cameraNode.addChild(shape). and yes you can change the sampling algorithm: set the filteringMode on an SKTexture. although note that any resampling will likely produce visual artifacts.

Thanks! I will definely try to attach them to the camera, but the downside is that these described nodes are tightly coupled to other (resizable) nodes: They draw an outline around the resizable nodes (and the outline should always appear to have the same line width). I think it might be possible, but this will of course add a lot of overhead of keeping track of size, position, rotation etc. I'm using SKShapeNode, unfortunately they don't seem to have filteringMode.

also note that SKShapeNodes are expensive to create. if you're trying to add outlines to nodes, you might explore using a shader -- it will be MUCH more performant. and if you want you can pass cameraScale as a variable input to the shader so the line width is always consistent
